# Why does my delegate only use the last item from my foreach loop?

Tags: c#, timer, delegates

**Scenario:** I am building a scheduling system and each timer event I wanted to run a custom method instead of the usual `Timer.Elapsed` event.

So I wrote something like this.

```
foreach (ScheduleElement schedule in schedules) {
    TimeSpan timeToRun = CalculateTime(schedule);
    schedule.Timer = new Timer(timeToRun.TotalMilliseconds);
    schedule.Timer.Elapsed += delegate { Refresh_Timer(schedule); };
    schedule.Timer.AutoReset = true;
    schedule.Timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Ok so simple enough that actually did create my timers. However, I wanted each elapsed event to run using the schedule element that it passed in. My question is, why does the Elapsed event only pass in the last ScheduleElement in the for loop for every single Timer.Elapsed event.

Now I know what fixes it, I am just not sure why. If I roll back to the original Timer.Elapsed event and extend the Timer class with my own class I can work around it. Like so.

**The Fix:**

```
foreach (ScheduleElement schedule in schedules) {
    TimeSpan timeToRun = CalculateTime(schedule);
    schedule.Timer = new TimerEx(timeToRun.TotalMilliseconds);
    schedule.Timer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Refresh_Timer);
    schedule.Timer.Tag = schedule;
    schedule.Timer.AutoReset = true;
    schedule.Timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

I then cast the `object sender` back into its original object, and thieve the `Tag` property off of it which gives me my correct schedule for each unique timer.

So again, why does using a `delegate { }` only pass in the last `ScheduleElement` in the foreach loop for all Timers?

**EDIT 1**

The Timer class

```
public TimerEx : Timer {

    public TimerEx(double interval) : base(interval) { }

    private Object _Tag;

    public Object Tag {
        get { return _Tag; }
        set { _Tag = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Research "Closing over the loop"

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-sharp-captured-variable-in-loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because you're using closure in your delegate, and it closes over the same variable, which is shared for each iteration of the foreach loop.

For details, see Eric Lippert's article [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

In this case, you can easily fix it with a temporary:

```
foreach (ScheduleElement schedule in schedules) {
    TimeSpan timeToRun = CalculateTime(schedule);
    schedule.Timer = new Timer(timeToRun.TotalMilliseconds);

    // Make a temporary variable in the proper scope, and close over it instead
    var temp = schedule;
    schedule.Timer.Elapsed += delegate { Refresh_Timer(temp); };
```

Note that  C# 5 changes this behavior for `foreach` loops. If you compile this with the latest compilers, the issue no longer exists.

Comment: Where can I find out more information on using the latest compiler? I am not really sure what my VS is using, I have 2010.

Comment: @meanbunny You'd need to use VS 2012 or later to get the new behavior.  It was changed in C# 5, which was released with VS 2012.

Comment: Ok thanks, great answer and I really appreciate it! Got 4 minutes left till I can accept.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that ReSharper underlines this as a "Access to modified closure" warning, and suggests the introduction of the temporary / iteration-scope variable.